# Why can't celery worker connect to rabbitmq using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery, celerybeat

I am trying to combine my services using docker compose but my celery and celery beat services can't connect with my rabbitmq service.
Here is my rabbitmq service in the docker-compose.yml file

```
rabbitmq:
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    depends_on:
      - server
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
```

and here are my celery worker and celery beat services in docker-compose.yml

```
celery_worker:
    container_name: celery-worker
    build: .
    command: celery -A tasks worker -E --loglevel=INFO
    environment:
      host_server: postgresqldb
      db_server_port: 5432
      database_name: db
      db_username: user
      db_password: password
      ssl_mode: prefer
    networks:
      - postgresqlnet
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

  celery_beat:
    container_name: celery-beat
    build: .
    command: celery -A tasks beat
    environment:
      - host_server=postgresqldb
      - db_server_port=5432
      - database_name=db
      - db_username=user
      - db_password=password
      - ssl_mode=prefer
    networks:
      - postgresqlnet
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

I also have a celeryconfig.py where broker url is stored. It's content are below

```
broker_url = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
```

When I run docker compose up I get this output from celery and celery beat.

```
celery-worker     | [2023-02-03 14:24:43,223: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
celery-worker     | Trying again in 32.00 seconds... (16/100)
celery-worker     | 
celery-beat       | [2023-02-03 14:25:10,058: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 32.0 seconds...
```

Comment: You're telling the Celery worker to try to connect to its own container, `localhost`.  That container isn't running the RabbitMQ broker.  Do you need to configure it using the Compose service name `rabbitmq` instead?

Comment: I changed the broker url to `broker_url="amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672//"` but I got this error 
`celery-worker     | [2023-02-03 14:39:53,378: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@rabbitmq:5672//: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`

Do I need to connect both services using docker networking? @DavidMaze

Comment: [Compose provides a network named `default` for you.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)  As you show it in the question, it looks like the RabbitMQ broker is on the `default` network but your Celery containers are on a separate `postgresqlnet` network.  I'd suggest deleting all of your existing `networks:` blocks for simplicity.

Comment: I created a network and added the rabbitmq, celery-worker and celery-beat services to it. And everything works well. Thank you sir @DavidMaze

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue where my Celery worker could not connect to the RabbitMQ service when orchestrated with Docker Compose. The solution that worked for me involved changing the network mode to host the involved services. This allows the services to communicate over the host's network, eliminating the need for port mappings and making service discovery straightforward since they can connect via *localhost*.

Here's how you can adjust your Docker Compose configuration:

For your RabbitMQ service:

```
rabbitmq:
  container_name: "rabbitmq"
  image: rabbitmq:3-management
  environment:
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
  volumes:
    - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
  network_mode: "host"
```

And for your Celery worker and Celery beat services:

```
celery_worker:
   #
   network_mode: "host"

celery_beat:
   # 
   network_mode: "host"
```

Make sure to adjust the broker_url in your celeryconfig.py to point to localhost or the host's IP address since all services are now on the host network:

```
broker_url = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
```

This configuration allows your Celery worker and beat services to successfully connect to RabbitMQ using localhost, as they're all utilizing the host's networking. Do note that using network_mode: "host" makes your services use the host's network stack directly, and this approach is typically more suited for Linux environments. It might behave differently on Docker for Windows or Mac, due to differences in how networking is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I realize what I did wrong now. First I needed to connect all three services using docker networking and then use the "rabbitmq" as my hostname name in my celeryconfig file.